# Group by array with first letter in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I Have array like

> ['Ajith', 'Arya', 'Akalya', 'Akila', 'Bharath', 'Bhakya', 'Kavitha',
> 'Kamal', 'Bavi']

I want ouptut like

```
   ['A',
    'Ajith',
    'Arya',
    'Akila',
    'B',
    'Bharath',
    'Bhakya',
    'Bavi',
    'k',
    'Kamal']
```

how can i acheive this in javascript
Help me and thanks advance

Answer (score 2):

You could group by first uppercase character with the character and all following items in a flat array.

```js
const
    data = ['Ajith', 'Arya', 'Akalya', 'Akila', 'Bharath', 'Bhakya', 'Kavitha', 'Kamal', 'Bavi'],
    result = Object
        .values(data.reduce((r, s) => {
            const key = s[0].toUpperCase();
            (r[key] ??= [key]).push(s);
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b))
        .flat();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do as your title says — 'group-by' first letter, then map the result.

```js
const input = ['Ajith', 'Arya', 'Akalya', 'Akila', 'Bharath', 'Bhakya', 'Kavitha', 'Kamal', 'Bavi',];


const grouped = {};

for (const word of input) {
  (grouped[word[0].toUpperCase()] ??= []).push(word);
}

const result = Object.entries(grouped).flatMap(([k, vs]) => [k, ...vs]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Can `reduce()` everything to an object, indexed by the first letter:

```js
const data = ['Ajith', 'Arya', 'Akalya', 'Akila', 'Bharath', 'Bhakya',
              'Kavitha', 'Kamal', 'Bavi'];

const result = [...data].sort().reduce((a, v) => {
  const [first] = v;
  a[first] ??= [];
  a[first].push(v);
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

This object will have the keys in the correct order because `sort()` was called first on (a copy of) the array, and string keys are maintained in insertion order.

If you want to convert that object to a flat array, you can just do:

```
const array = Object.keys(result).flatMap((k) => [k, ...result[k]]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution, probably not the most optimized one, but it should work :

The idea is to sort the array, loop over all the elements to compare the first letter in order to create a subgroup title.

It would look something like this :

```js
var displaySortedArray = function(array) {
  var sortedArray = array.sort();
  console.log(sortedArray[0].charAt(0));
  console.log(sortedArray[0]);
  for(let index = 1 ; index < sortedArray.length ; index++){
    if(sortedArray[index].charAt(0) != sortedArray[index-1].charAt(0)){
      console.log(sortedArray[index].charAt(0));
    }
    console.log(sortedArray[index]);
  }
}

displaySortedArray(['Test','SUUUU','Easy','Try2','Elements','Super','Amazing']);
```

This function is an example and prints what you asked for, however i can't tell you how to implement this where you need it.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to do using a single `reduce` call which I find quite elegant:

```js
const data = ['Ajith', 'Arya', 'Akalya', 'Akila', 'Bharath', 'Bhakya', 'Kavitha', 'Kamal', 'Bavi'];
console.log(
  data
    .sort()
    .reduce(
      (items, item, index, array) => {
        console.log({ prev: array[index - 1], current: item });
        if (array[index - 1]?.[0] !== item[0]) {
          items.push(item[0]);
        }

        items.push(item);
        return items;
      },
      []
    )
);
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/tomashubelbauer/pen/RwBBvPV?editors=0011)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Seems simpler than what was posted so far

```js
const arr = ['Ajith', 'Arya', 'Akalya', 'Akila', 'Bharath', 'Bhakya', 'Kavitha', 'Kamal', 'Bavi']
const newArr = arr
  .slice() // copy 
  .sort();
let letter = "";  
for (let i=0; i<newArr.length; i++) {
  const thisLetter = newArr[i].charAt(0);
  if (thisLetter !== letter) {
    letter = thisLetter;
    newArr.splice(i,0,thisLetter)
  }
}  
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Several good answers are already here. This one may be a little bit simpler:

```js
const arr = ['Ajith', 'Arya', 'Akalya', 'Akila', 'Bharath', 'Bhakya', 'Kavitha', 'Kamal', 'Bavi'].sort();
for(let i = arr.length -1; i>=0; i--) {
    if(i === 0 || arr[i][0] !== arr[i-1][0]) arr.splice(i,0, arr[i][0]);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let d=["Ajith","Arya","Akalya","Akila",
  "Bharath","Bhakya","Kavitha","Kamal","Bavi"].sort()
  
let r=[...new Set(d.map(([c])=>c))].flatMap(c=>[c, ...d.filter(([i])=>i==c)])

console.log(r)
```

or:

```js
let d = ["Ajith","Arya","Akalya","Akila",
  "Bharath","Bhakya","Kavitha","Kamal","Bavi"].sort()

let r = Object.values(d.map(s=>
  [s.charAt(0),s]).reduce((c,[a,b])=>((c[a]??=[a]).push(b),c),{})).flat()

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let names = ['Ajith', 'Arya', 'Akalya', 'Akila', 'Bharath', 'Bhakya', 'Kavitha', 'Kamal', 'Bavi'];

let result = [];

let firstLetters = new Set();
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  firstLetters.add(names[i][0]);
}

firstLetters = Array.from(firstLetters).sort();
for (let i = 0; i < firstLetters.length; i++) {
  result.push(firstLetters[i]);
  for (let j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
    if (names[j][0] === firstLetters[i]) {
      result.push(names[j]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: that is a lot of extra processing

Answer (score 0):

You can use map

```js
let names = ['Ajith', 'Arya', 'Akalya', 'Akila', 'Bharath', 'Bhakya', 'Kavitha', 'Kamal', 'Bavi'];

let map = new Map();
names.forEach(item => {
  let firstLetter = item[0].toUpperCase();
  if (!map.has(firstLetter)) {
    map.set(firstLetter, [firstLetter]);
  }
  map.get(firstLetter).push(item);
});

let result = [];
map.forEach(value => {
  result.push(...value);
});

console.log(result);
```

You can also make every letter a separate group

```js
let name = ['Ajith', 'arya', 'Akalya', 'Akila', 'Bharath', 'Bhakya', 'Kavitha', 'Kamal', 'Bavi'];

let map = new Map();
name.forEach(item => {
  let firstLetter = item[0].toUpperCase();
  if (!map.has(firstLetter)) {
    map.set(firstLetter, [firstLetter]);
  }
  map.get(firstLetter).push(item);
});

let result = [];
map.forEach(value => {
  result.push(value);
});

console.log(result);
```